# In Naruto Shippuden episode 467, how was a normal villager able to use jutsu?

Tags: naruto

There was a scene in Episode 467 of Naruto Shippuden, where Ashura taught ninjutsu to a villager.

But I have been led to understand that only descendants of Kaguya can use jutsu (because originally Kaguya was the origin of chakra).

How can they use jutsu if they're not descendants of Kaguya?

Comment: Shinpunden? or  Shippuden?

Comment: IN addition to the answers, It is also Filler, so it breaks a LOT of rules. Asura did not have the Sharingan according to Canon (or at least was never told/shown to have had it), as well, Hagoromo was never shown with anything besides the Rinnegan in canon. Quite a bit of story conflicts with what was said in the manga.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you are right but :

> Hagoromo travelled across the land, giving chakra to everyone in the
>   world as well as spreading his ideals and religion

so it is possible that Ashura might have just shared his chakra just as his father [Hagoromo](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hagoromo_%C5%8Ctsutsuki) did.